Why there is space between the images in subfigures
Why there is space between the images in subfigures? Also, the space is not even. How could I fix that?
Notice, that I change the images for privacy.
%----------------------------
\begin{figure*}[h]%[htbp]
\begin{subfigure}
 
  \centering
 \includegraphics[width=170mm]%139mm
 {images/header.PNG}
 % \caption{$y=x$}
 \label{fig:y equals x}
 \end{subfigure}


\begin{minipage}{0.248\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth, angle =-90]{images/s_gt_35_66.PNG}
\label{fig:1a}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.248\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth, angle =-90]{images/s_utrans_35_66.PNG}
\label{fig:1b}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.248\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth, angle =-90]{images/s_swing_35_66.PNG}
\label{fig:1c}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.248\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth, angle =-90]{images/s_ours_35_66.PNG}
\label{fig:1c}
\end{minipage}


%-------------------------------

%-------------------------------
%-----------------4-------------
\begin{minipage}{0.248\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth, angle =-90]{images/s_gt_8_117.PNG}
\label{fig:1a}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.248\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth, angle =-90]{images/s_utrans_8_117.PNG}
\label{fig:1b}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.248\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth, angle =-90]{images/s_swing_8_117.PNG}
\label{fig:1c}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.248\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth, angle =-90]{images/s_ours_8_117.PNG}
\label{fig:1c}
\end{minipage}

%-------------------------------

 
 
 \caption{ Qualitative comparison of random  slices from  dataset}
 \label{fig:figure02182}
\end{figure*}



Pretty much symbols - What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange. Add % after \end{minipage}.

Or boxes - Minipage inside framebox creates an undesired horizontal spacing - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange

@user202729 yes, its better now, when I added % to all \end{minipage}% the space becomes the same. But is there a way to remove the space.

Your images only fill part of the minipage

It's because of your width=0.95\textwidth isn't it? Is fill the whole thing (and delete all whitespaces) enough?

is there away to reduce the box of the minipage so that it fit the image exactly? @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

@user836026: Can you clarify what the output should look like? For example, do you want the images to be touching one another and fill the entire text block horizontally? Or, fill it horizontally with some (equal) space between?

@user836026 If you want the the image to fill the whole minipage,  don't scale it down to only 95% and instead use width=1\textwidth

you could simply remove the minipage as they are doing nothing useful

Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
. It worked!

your question asks about space between images in subfigures, but your rows of four images with space between are not in a subfigure they are directly in figure

I apologize.. yes. my question was framed incorrectly.
